# Implementing RLS/DRLS in SSAS Tabular vs Power BI

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular

I want to know the difference between implementing RLS or DRLS in SSAS vs Power BI.

If we are implementing it in SSAS tabular should we implement it in the Power BI also ?

We are using an SSAS tabular cube as a datasource for our Power BI report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we are implementing it in SSAS tabular should we implement it in the Power BI also ?

No.  RLS is implemented in the tabular model.  If your tabular model is hosted in SSAS, and your Power BI uses Live Connect mode, then it will use the RLS in the Tabular Model.

Comment: We are using composite models

Comment: Then you may need to implement RLS in the local model.

Comment: You mean in Power BI ? but what if we are using DirectQuery over Import?

Comment: For DirectQuery RLS will be active in the remote tabular model, but you may need additional RLS in the local model.  But using composite models is very new and this is one of the reasons it adds complexity to your solution.  Live Connect is still preferred if possible.

Comment: But we still cannot do the Live Connect with many SAAS tabular sources at the same time right ?

Comment: Correct.  In the basic model, each PowerBI report is connected to a single tabular model.  99% of the time that's still the correct approach.